# React.Children.map recursively?

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a React Component for rendering an HTML form and I'm finding the need to recursively iterate through all children of my parent Form component in order to add extra props to only children components of a certain Type.

An example (in JSX):

```
<Form>
    <p>Personal Information</p>
    <Input name="first_name" />
    <Input name="last_name" />
    <Input name="email" />
    <Label>
        Enter Your Birthday
        <Input name="birthday" type="date" />
    </Label>
</Form>
```

In this example, I'm using React.Children.map inside my Form component, and then inside the map function I'm checking the child's "type" and the child's "type.displayName" to determine what element I'm dealing with (either a native HTML element or a ReactElement):

```
var newChildren = React.Children.map(this.props.children, function(child) {
    if (is.inArray(child.type.displayName, supportedInputTypes)) {
      var extraChildProps = {
        alertColor: this.props.alertColor,
        displayErrors: this.state.displayErrors
      }
      return React.cloneElement(child, extraChildProps);
    } else {
      return child;
    }
  }.bind(this));
```

My problem is that React.Children.map only shallowly iterates through this.props.children, and I would like it to also check children of children of children, etc.  I need to add props to only my Input components so that they know when to display errors, and which color the error message should be displayed, etc.  In the example above, the birthday input does not receive the necessary props, because it is wrapped in a Label component.

Any plan for React.Children.map to have a "recursive" mode or any other utility out there that can accomplish what I'm trying to do?

At the end of the day, I would like to write a single function that maps through each and every child (even nested ones) in order to perform an operation on it (in this case cloning).

Comment: I figured out a way to work around the specific problem I was trying to solve, so I no longer need to implement this specific recursive iteration feature, but it would be really cool to hear of potential ways to solve this problem from others who may have encountered this need.

Comment: This is the kind of problem you solve by avoiding the problem. Using React.Children.map at all is a red flag that you're doing something complicated and confusing.

Comment: Agreed.  I see that using higher-order components and/or mixins (temporarily) and/or something like a global flux store is the way to prevent having to use this method.  In my specific use case it was the Formsy.Mixin that came to my rescue as I was able to determine when to "displayErrors" simply by calling the Formsy mixin function isFormSubmitted() which solved my problem without having to clone children with extra props.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand if you want to always write a bunch of boilerplate code to inject `value`, `onChange`, and validation props to your form controls, by all means do it.  But one day I got tired of doing that, figured out how to inject them all using recursive cloning, turned it into a library (https://github.com/jedwards1211/react-bind-data), created another library to get rid of all the redux boilerplate (https://github.com/jedwards1211/react-bind-data-redux), and sped up my development time dramatically.  Recursive cloning is really the only way to do this right now.

Answer (score 48):

While not baked into React, this is certainly possible:

```
import React from "react";

function recursiveMap(children, fn) {
  return React.Children.map(children, child => {
    if (!React.isValidElement(child)) {
      return child;
    }

    if (child.props.children) {
      child = React.cloneElement(child, {
        children: recursiveMap(child.props.children, fn)
      });
    }

    return fn(child);
  });
}
```

If you'd like to avoid copy / pasting the above you can also use [this npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-itertools) I authored.

Comment: This is working beautifully. But just to mention there is a missing closing parentheses throwing a syntax error.

Comment: Anyone know what the passed in `fn` / callback is supposed to do?

Comment: `fn` is supposed to do whatever you want. For instance, `fn = child => React.cloneElement(child, { myNewProp: 'imporant new info' })`

Comment: This doesn't recurse into React `connect()`-ed components. This checks `child.props`.. is there a way to have it recurse into all child elements?

Comment: Not sure this has to do with `connect` but more the fact that if a child is `<AnotherComponent>`, it won't loop onto the rendered component (eg. `<div className="another-component"><MySubComponent /></div>`. Any solution to achieve this?

Comment: anybody know how to get typescript to grok this? its being a pain here with types

Comment: Seems that declaring `child` as `ReactNode` type should solve the types issues, here: `return React.Children.map(children, (child: ReactNode) => {...})`

Comment: Same note as @augustin — This is only recursive until it encounters a component with no children, and then it stops recursively getting those components’ children. Not sure how to handle that case though.

Comment: @MatthewDean and AugustinRiedinger those aren't children of the React component in question -- those are the internal implementation details of another component. You can not inspect elements inside of another component, you will need to lift those elements out of the component and into the parent if you want to recursively map over them.

Comment: That can be achieved with child composition: Eg `<Parent><Foo /></Parent>` will need to become `<Parent><Foo><SomeChildThatWasInFoo /><MaybeAnotherChildThatWasInFoo /></Foo></Parent>`

Answer (score 8):

I've made a small library to deal with the Children structure. You can check it here:

https://github.com/fernandopasik/react-children-utilities

In your case you can use the method deepMap:

```
import React from 'react';
import Children from 'react-children-utilities';

var newChildren = Children.deepMap(this.props.children, function(child) {
    if (is.inArray(child.type.displayName, supportedInputTypes)) {
      var extraChildProps = {
        alertColor: this.props.alertColor,
        displayErrors: this.state.displayErrors
      }
      return React.cloneElement(child, extraChildProps);
    } else {
      return child;
    }
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: I had to import this way with typescript to make it work: const Children = require('react-children-utilities/dist').default

Comment: This package is awesome, works great for my case. Thanks!!

Comment: @Porkopek the package is in typescript now, it should be easier to import

Answer (score 6):

This thread actually misses the right answer:

```
const mapRecursive = (children, callback) => (
  React.Children.map(
    children,
    child => (
      child.props.children
        ? [callback(child), mapRecursive(child.props.children, callback)]
        : callback(child)
    ),
  )
);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to push props into a set of children under your component "automatically", you can also use [context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html). This allows you to "give" properties, functions, etc. to child components by providing them from the parent with `childContextTypes` and `getChildContext()`, and having the child "request" them with `contextTypes`.

Comment: context is great and works for a lot of things.  However, it only works if the children are written to support it.  Recursive cloning, on the other hand, allows you to inject properties to **any** components, even ones that don't use context.  My favorite use case: injecting `value` and `onChange` props (shameless plug: https://github.com/jedwards1211/react-bind-data)

Comment: Your shameless plug just saved me a lot of time.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

My typescript version of the accepted answer.

```js
const recursiveMap = (
  children: ReactElement[],
  fn: (child: ReactElement) => ReactElement
): ReactElement[] => {
  return React.Children.map(children, child => {
    if (!React.isValidElement(child)) {
      return child;
    }

    if ((child as ReactElement).props.children) {
      const props = {
        children: recursiveMap((child as ReactElement).props.children, fn)
      }
      child = React.cloneElement(child, props);
    }

    return fn(child);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer to this is that its not currently possible as of React 0.14.  As FakeRainBrigand mentioned, its more than likely a code smell anyway, so it should prompt a reevaluation of your implementation.

Comment: This is possible, it just isn't available as part of the React 0.14 Top-Level API.

Answer (score 0):

in my case I write a recursive function which renders item of list and it's children

```
export const MenuCatalog: FC = () => {
return (
    <div style = {{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column'}>
        {recursive(testMenuData)}
    </div>
)
}
```

my nested array:

```
const testMenuData = [
{
    name: '1',
    children: []
},
{
    name: '1',
    children: [
        {
            name: 'sub 1',
            children: []
        },
        {
            name: 'sub 2',
            children: []
        },
        {
            name: 'sub 3',
            children: [
                {
                    name: 'sub sub 1',
                    children: []
                },
                {
                    name: 'sub sub 2',
                    children: []
                },
                {
                    name: 'sub sub 3',
                    children: []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    name: '3',
    children: []
},
]
```

recursive function:

```
const recursive = (array: any, isChild?: boolean) => {
return (
    array.map(item => (
        <>
            <CatalogMenuItem isChild = {isChild} name={item.name}/>
            {item?.children.length ? recursive(item.children, true) : null }
        </>
    ))
)
}
```

and custom component for render items:

```
export const CatalogMenuItem: FC<{name: string, isChild?: boolean}> = ({name, isChild}) => {
return (
    <div className = {styles.cont} style = {isChild && {marginLeft: 10}}>{name}</div>
)
}
```