# React: Adding props only to React component and not html tag (React.Children.map recursively)

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs

I have a `Form`'s React component that manage several `Field`'s component and attach to them some props.
Until now, I created only simple form, like this

```
<Form>
    <FieldText/>
    <FieldDropdown />
</Form>
```

but now, I need a form with more complex structure, like this

```
<Form>
    <div>
        <a data-tab="first">First Tab</a>
        <a data-tab="second">Second Tab</a>
    </div>

    <div data-tab="first">
        <FieldText />
    </div>

    <div data-tab="second">
        <FieldText />
    </div>
</Form>
```

With simple form I added props to `Field`in this way

```
var Form = React.createClass({

    render: function(){
        <form onSubmit={this.submit} acceptCharset="UTF-8" ref={cForm.id}>
            {
                React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => {

                    // if type is funtion the is a react component
                    if( typeof child.type === "function"){

                        return  React.cloneElement(child, {
                            attachToForm: this.attachToForm,
                            disabled: this.props.disabled
                        });

                     } else {

                         return child;
                     }

               })

            }
        </form>
    }

});
```

How can I modify `Form` to add some props only to `Field`'s component and not 
html tag?

Answer (score 1):

Each child component should have a `type` field, for normal html elements, this would be a string such as "span", "div", etc.

You can simply `switch` (or your conditional of choice) against that field.

Simple abstracted version would be like:

```
const Foo = (props) => (
  <div style={props.style}>FOO</div>
);

class App extends React.Component {
  render () {           
    return (
      <div>
        { React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => {

          if(typeof child.type === 'string') {
              switch(child.type) {
                case 'span':
                  return React.cloneElement(child, { style: { background: 'pink' }});
                case 'div':
                  return React.cloneElement(child, { style: { background: 'red' }});
              }
          } else {
              switch(child.type.name) {
                case 'Foo':
                  return React.cloneElement(child, { style: { background: 'blue' }});
              }
          }
          return child;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App>
    <span>span</span>
    <p>p</p>
    <Foo />
    <div>div</div>
  </App>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

With codepen:

http://codepen.io/cjke/pen/qRQvmY?editors=0010

**EDIT**
Based on the comments, the question is more about recursively walking the DOM tree - in which, its simple a duplicate of this question: [React.Children.map recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32916786/react-children-map-recursively)

Comment: I know that, in fact I used 'child.type' to determine if child is a function or not. I can't to figure out how create a recursive method to add inside Form the html tag and and adding new props only to field component (if field is inside another html tag)

Comment: If "you knew that" then you need to reconsider the wording of your question - the last line asks how can I tell the difference between a component and a html element. It says nothing about recursively walking down the DOM tree.

Comment: Sorry, but my english is bad so it is more difficult for me explain myself. In your example, if you put 'Foo' inside the last div, 'Foo' will be red and not blue. This is my issue