# How to map the un-immediate children of a component passed down as a child (React)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component, which should check if there is a certain element type passed as a child. This should happen in componentWillMount.

Iteration is easy, if the child elements are immediate.

The problems start, when there is a component, which might have certain element type, passed down. React.Children.map does not return the children of the component.

```
class Nested extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return(
      <div className='wrapper'>
        <div className='how-to-access' />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Modifier extends React.Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        const { children } = this.props
        React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
            /* In here I would like to check/modify
             * the props of children of the immediate
             * children.
             */
            console.log(child.props.children) // undefined
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (this.props.children)
    }
}

class Wrapper extends React.Component {

    render() {
        <Modifier>
            <Nested />
        </Modifier>
    }
}
```

I know how to use refs, but that does not help, since I don't want the rendered elements back, but to manipulate the deep nested component props.

How do I gain access to/"deep map" the "un-immediate" children?

Ps. I don't know what is the opposite of immediate child, so sorry for my terminology.

Comment: You can't access the elements rendered by the `Nested` component in `componentWillMount` because those elements don't exist before the component has been rendered. Why do you need to manipulate the props?
 Could you perhaps just pass down a prop to `Nested` instead?

Comment: @fson I am making a component which I don't always know what is going to be passed as a child - is it just elements or another component. It is also part experimental, probably I am breaking all best practices here. So: no, I can't pass the props to Nested. Why I want to do this, well, that is harder to explain. I just need to find if there is input elements rendered inside any of the children/components.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React.Children.map recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32916786/react-children-map-recursively)