# React: Get component order within hierarchy

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement helper components for CSS Grids.  I have something like (prepare yourself):

```
<ColumnContainer columns={[ "1em", "1fr", "auto", "auto", "1em", "auto"]}>
  <ColumnContainer.Row>
    { rowIdx => (
      <div style={{ gridRow: rowIdx, gridColumn: "1 / 3" }}>
      </div>
    )}
  </ColumnContainer.Row>
</ColumnContainer>
```

`ColumnContainer`:

- Is a container `div` with `display: grid` and various grid properties set up
- Is also a context provider

Then, `ColumnContainer.Row`:

- Is basically a context consumer
- Takes a function as a child
- Doesn't need to be a direct child of `ColumnContainer` - hence using context

The context provided is an integer, `layoutVersion`, which is incremented whenever the set of rows is intended to change (to trigger a re-render), and - hack of hacks - an empty array.

The idea is, as each `ColumnContainer.Row` renders, it adds itself (could be any object) to the array whose reference is passed in the context, and renders the child function with the size of the array as the parameter (row index).

Believe it or not, this works, for the first render and if rows are just added to the end.

However, when components are added in the "middle" of the component DOM, the resulting rendered rows are out-of-order (but not overlapping).  Meaning, I think, that in the case of a new layout version (re-render), all the `ColumnContainer.Row`s are re-rendered, but not necessarily in the 'natural' order they are in, i.e. in the DOM.

My guess is that depending on components to have `render()` called in a certain order is a bad idea, as well as modifying the contents of context properties in `render()`.

What are my other options - what I really want is to know the 'natural' order of descendent nodes within a component tree.  If they were direct child elements, I'd guess it would be easy - in my case though I have nested components which can output rows.

Comment: Edit: have tried doing a recursive map using something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/42498730/376409, but that doesn't look to work with redux-`connect()`-ed components, i.e. it won't recurse into them :'(

Comment: how are rows rendered

Comment: Could you elaborate on that question please @ShubhamKhatri ? The example above shows how I'd like the `Row` component to be used

Comment: It looks like your problem could related to React reconcilation. Have you tried to use React's `key` ?

Comment: @FiriceNguyen I'm not sure I can see what you mean. There's no mapping/array and so I can't see how a key would come in to it?

Comment: @KierenJohnstone If you could please add snippets of your code and screenshots of how it looks with your solution and then a small description of how it should look like, it would really help us out in answering your question.

Comment: @yeshashah - the code I have doesn't solve it / doesn't work. I think I described the problem pretty fully, but if you have a specific question or two I'll be very happy to elaborate?

Comment: @KierenJohnstone i believe Firice is suggesting you try adding key={ rowIdx } to your div in your code snippet.

Comment: @james - that makes no sense at all to me. I don't need a key - I need to determine the rowIdx to pass in to the child you see rendered there

Comment: @KierenJohnstone it's possible this isn't your issue... but it sounds like it to me (and FiriceNguyen): https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys and this CodePen demonstrates the same behavior you describe: https://reactjs.org/redirect-to-codepen/reconciliation/index-used-as-key

Comment: @james, that's not my issue, but thank you for the attention/thought

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a dodgy/hacky solution, by having child components 'register' themselves (a unique ID and ref) with the container component via a callback injected in the context.

The container component accumulates these callbacks using functional state updates and setting a flag in the state that a re-calc is required.

The container's `componentDidUpdate` checks the re-calc flag and compares all of the DOM notes (via the refs) using the browser DOM function `compareDocumentPosition`.  The next state update clears the re-calc flag and includes the order of each of the children's IDs.

This state is then passed down to all children via context, where they can look up their index by ID.

Clearly that sucks but it's all I have for now.  Would still like to award bounty to a better solution.

Comment: I find this question fascinating, if you could toss your whole example in a codepen I would love to see it. Originally I thought, along with some of the other comments that it was indeed a reconciliation problem. I think your solution is probably sufficient but a code example would be cool

Comment: This is the solution that I arrived at as well

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you rely on `render()` to provide you with the recursive structure inside your `DOM Tree`. The reason it works "the first time" is that all the components need to be rendered the first time they are presented to `react`.

However, subsequent `render()` calls on `ColumnContainer` do not imply renders on the sub-components because their `state` or `props` might have not changed.

I think you should try the following:

1. Change your `ColumnContainer.Row` registration to the `ColumnContainer` array in a way that the children *rembember* `rowIdx` in their `state` on the first call and then reuse this value for subsequent `render` calls.

(so to do this effectively you would need:)

2. Change your registration procedure in two function calls (these two functions should be in your context):

   - a function that gets the `rowIdx` for a child and remembers it. (this function is only called if you don't have a cached value for `rowIdx`)
   - a second function that does the work but does not need `rowIdx` as a parameter. (this function is called just like now, every time).

Comment: I cant see how this would work if something is inserted i to the array? In that case, React doesnt even re render everything in the right order, even if they all need to be re rendered