# Recursively clone and modify children in React - including other components' children

Tags: reactjs

I've read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/42498730/64105, and it works fine for running through all elements from `<TitleList>` and down when rendered like this:

```
  <TitlesList>
    <ul>
      <li>First</li>
      <li>Second</li>
      <li>Third</li>
    </ul>
  </TitlesList>
```

... but not when split into multiple components, like:

```
const List = () => (
  <ul>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
  </ul>
);

<TitlesList>
  <List />
</TitlesList>
```

Is there a way to recurse into the child components on render and clone/modify their elements too?

For a running sample, see https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-ives-c8df0

Answer (score 3):

This is what I needed to modify in order to make it work:

```js
function recursiveMap(children, fn) {
  return React.Children.map(children, child => {
    if (!React.isValidElement(child)) {
      return child;
    }

    if (typeof child.type === "function") {
      child = child.type();
    }

    if (child.props.children) {
      child = React.cloneElement(child, {
        children: recursiveMap(child.props.children, fn)
      });
    }

    return fn(child);
  });
}
```

I noticed that when a component is passed as a child, `child.type` is a function, instead of an object. So in order to get the component's children, you just have to call `child.type()`.

[Here is the CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-dust-hwdtb).

Comment: Thanks! Two things that spring to mind: 1. Is it ok to prematurely render a component and replace it with it's result? I guess in a purely functional world, this should work, but I wonder what happens if the component use state or is wrapped? 2. Could this work for class components?

Comment: Hmm. Very interesting questions. I’ll do some research, try out some stuff and I’ll share my results & opinion.

Comment: @asgerhallas I couldn't find a way to implement such behavior with class components. Regarding the first question, I don't think the current way of doing things offers much flexibility. Just wondering, why did you have to clone elements in the first place?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! I have actually come across the need several times, but I admit mostly out of curiosity. Currently it's for a kind of table component for ReactPdf and I was trying to see if I could make it without use of special components for things like rows and cells, just relying on the default components and the given structure - which means I must dive into the tree and add props to elements.