# How to access data in React.Children or props.children?

Tags: reactjs, react-props, children

So I'm trying to get some data from `props.children` or `React.Children` but I'm not being able to, this is what I'm doing:

```
console.log(props.children)
```

This prints this on the console:

```
[
  0: {
     $$typeof: Symbol(react.element)
     key: "slide-id-0"
     props: {section: {…}, onChange: ƒ}
     ...
  }
  1: {
     $$typeof: Symbol(react.element)
     key: "slide-id-1"
     props: {section: {…}, onChange: ƒ}
     ...
  }

]
```

And if i try to loop through it like this:

```
React.Children.map(children, child => (
        console.log(child)
    ))
```

I get the two objects:

```
0: {
     $$typeof: Symbol(react.element)
     key: "slide-id-0"
     props: {section: {…}, onChange: ƒ}
     ...
  }
  1: {
     $$typeof: Symbol(react.element)
     key: "slide-id-1"
     props: {section: {…}, onChange: ƒ}
     ...
  }
```

Now, what I want is to access the section inside the props component inside the object, but if I try to do this:

```
React.Children.map(children, child => (
        console.log(child.props)
    ))
```

I get this error:

> Property 'props' does not exist on type 'string | number | boolean | {} | ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor> | ReactNodeArray | ReactPortal'.
> Property 'props' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)

How can I access that data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it working, i used this other question as reference: [React.Children.map recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32916786/react-children-map-recursively)

And i this is what i did:

```
React.Children.map(children, child => {
        if (!React.isValidElement(child)) {
          return child;
        }
    
        if (child.props) {
            console.log(child.props.section)
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can returns the children  as a flat array with keys assigned to each child with [react-children-to-array](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrentoarray), then iterate it with a `.map()`

```js
React.Children.toArray(props.children).map(({ props })=> console.log(props))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using typescript, you could solve it by typing children props to be **ReactElement**, then you can access to any properties inside.

It's not necessary to use `isValidElement` by this way.